# Cannot convert value of type 'UUID' to expected argument type 'KeyPath<Item, ID>' in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, foreach, swiftui

I'm implementing my own custom Grid in SwiftUI. I'm using generics to lay out an array of given items in a Grid fashion. I want them to be animated so I need to specify an id for ForEach within Grid implementation. How to specify id since items are generics.

I thought of using UUID I got the following error

> Cannot convert the value of type 'UUID' to expected argument type
> 'KeyPath<Item, ID>'

Also, I tried `id: \.self` - I'm getting following error:

> Generic struct 'ForEach' requires that 'Item' conform to 'Hashable'

Here is my Grid code:

```
struct Grid<Item, ItemView> : View where Item : Identifiable, ItemView : View{
    private var items : Array<Item>
    private var viewForItem : (Item) -> ItemView
    
    init(_ items: Array<Item>, viewForItem: @escaping (Item) -> ItemView) {
        self.items = items
        self.viewForItem = viewForItem
    }
    
    func getLayout(itemsCount: Int, size: CGSize) -> GridLayout {
        GridLayout(itemCount: itemsCount, in: size)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            
            ForEach(self.items, id: \.self) { item in
               self.viewForItem(item)
                .frame(width: self.getLayout(itemsCount: self.items.count, size: geometry.size).itemSize.width,
                       height: self.getLayout(itemsCount: self.items.count, size: geometry.size).itemSize.height)
                        .position(self.getLayout(itemsCount: self.items.count, size: geometry.size)
                        .location(ofItemAt: self.items.firstIndex(of: item)!))
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Here is my model:

```
struct SetGame {
    var deck : Array<SetCard> = []
    var playingTwelveDeck : Array<SetCard> = []  
}
```

```
struct SetCard : Identifiable, Hashable {
    var color : ColorValue
    var shapeName : ShapeName
    var shading : Shadings
    var count : Int
    var isSelected = false
    var isMatched = false
    var position : Int
    var isSelectedAnimationToggle : Bool
    var id = UUID()
}
```

Im using `SetGame.SetCard` as my item in Grid.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to constrain `Item` to `Hashable` you can do:

```
struct Grid<Item, ItemView>: View 
    where Item: Identifiable & Hashable, // <- add `Hashable`
          ItemView: View 
{ ... }
```

Comment: after that what should the id be? \.self or something else

Comment: This is the parameter by which ForEach differentiates items. It can be a specific property (eg. `id: \.id` for Identifiable) or it can be the whole item (provided it conforms to Hashable) - then you can do `id:\.self`.